# an inverted trapezoid but if the input height is too large for the width, then it should report, Impossible (what an "impossible shape" would be)

Tags: c++

I have this assignment:

> Write a program trapezoid.cpp that prints an upside-down trapezoid of
>   given width and height.
>
> However, if the input height is impossibly large for the given width,
>   then the program should report, Impossible shape!

*Example 1:*

```
Input width: 12 Input height: 5  
Shape:

************
 **********  
  ********         
   ******      
    ****
```

*Example 2:*

```
Input width: 12 Input height: 7

Impossible shape!
```

I need help trying to figure out what an impossible trapezoid would be. This is my code, so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{    
    int rows, width, height, spaces, stars; // declare values

    cout << "enter width" << endl;
    cin >> width;

    cout << "enter height" << endl;
    cin >> height;

    for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row) {
        for (int col = height + row; col > 0; --col) {

            if (height % 6 == 1) { 
                cout << "Impossible shape!" << endl;

                return 0;
            }
            cout << " ";
        }

        for (int col = 0; col < (width - 2 * row); ++col) {
            cout << "*";

            spaces += 1;
            stars -= 2;
        }
        cout << endl;
```

Comment: Does the code work? Does it not work? If the latter, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I can get the Trapezoid to work perfect. I'm having trouble with the "Impossible trapezoid" part. I don't understand what that would exactly be, I edited the question my teacher sent me in the original post, sorry about that

Comment: Your trapezoids have 45° lateral edges, so the height can't be greater than half the width (think at it as a truncated triangle).

Comment: Why do you think that `(height % 6 == 1)` is the right test for an impossible shape?  If you explain your reasoning, you'll learn more from this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of asterisks in the shape starts with the width at the top level and then decreases by 2 for each subsequent level. Once the bottom level is 2 asterisks wide, you cannot have another level below it. Therefore, the maximum height for a width k, where k is an even integer, is k / 2. I will leave the case where k is an odd integer for you to determine yourself.